# Unrecognized option 'map 0:a?'

Tags: bash, unix, ffmpeg

Trying to make derivatives of silent video files is failing. My understanding is adding a trailing ? to the -map option makes ffmpeg ignore that stream if it does not exist, but its not working. The full script is below.

```
ffmpeg -n -vsync 0 -nostdin -v info -hide_banner -stats -i "${FILE}" -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:v -map 0:a? -c:v libx264 -vf "yadif=1,format=yuv420p" -crf "${CRFVALUE}" -preset "${PRESETSPEED}" -maxrate "${MAXRATE}"k -bufsize 1835k -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -f mp4 "${OUTPUT}"
```

withouth the ? after -map 0:a it works with files containing audio streams but not with silent ones. with the ? it fails all files. from the ffmpeg documentation: "A trailing ? will allow the map_channel to be optional: if the map_channel matches no channel the map_channel will be ignored instead of failing."

why isn't it working here?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com/), being a question about tool usage (equally fit to interactive uses as scripting) and not the bash language.

Comment: Maybe you have a single-character filename in the current directory, and the `?` is getting replaced with the filename by your shell. I would try quoting the `?` with single quotes, just to be sure.

Comment: @EricBackus no all the file names look akin to this: 2012_79_1_4_1_R4_DER_01.mov

Comment: Your command uses `-map` but the error relates to `-map_channel`. Add -report and rerun your command. Share report.

Comment: @EricBackus putting single quotes around the ? solved it. Thanks!